# Do I have to configure PHP everytime I add a new site to my server?

Tags: php

I'm standing in as the net admin for my company and learning on the job. I just added a new site to our server, and it works fine all except for the php email contact form. Do I have to configure php to let it know there is a new site that uses it?

Comment: Usually no. What errors do you get?

Comment: No you don't. It is probably an error to do with your script - what errors are you getting?

Comment: No errors,...it just wont work, if there is an error log, I dont know where to look.  this is the URL : www.productphotos1.com/index-5.html

Comment: If you fill out the form, the email never gets to me. the only parameter in the code is to add my email address to the code (view the source line 96) and the template people say it should just work, ta daaa!, No dice

Comment: Not sure,..how do I see error logs?  <----NOOB

Answer (score 0):

you need more detail here, nobody knows what your 'email contact form' is.

If you mean modifying PHP code for each site... yeah you have to do that if your code calls for it.

As far as adding a new vhost to apache that happens to run PHP as a module, you shouldn't need to modify PHP unless there are software extensions you need (GD / DB extensions etc) for that site/app.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you're using vhosts with apache then you might need to set the sendmail path

```
php_admin_value sendmail_path "/path/to/sendmail -t -i -f joe@smith.com"
```

Comment: I am using the vhost with apache, and Ill try that

Comment: Again,..Im a noob here, so when you say vhost, are you meaning httpd-vhost.conf??

Comment: Sorry yea I do mean in the vhosts file